# Cannot writeToFile to NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)

Tags: ios, swift, writetofile

I'd like to save to file NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true). I've written code as following, however it cannot save file on cachedirectory, its success becomes false. Could you tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you for your kindness.

```
    let paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .CachesDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)
    let cachesPath: AnyObject = paths2[0]

    var user:NSDictionary = [
        "Name": "Tom",
        "Address": "Tokyo",
    ]

    let success = user.writeToFile(cachesPath as! String, atomically: true)

    if success {
        println("save sucess")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to save a file with the path of the `Caches` directory. You can only write a file to a file path. To create a file path you append the name of the file to the directory you want to save it in like so:

```
let paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .CachesDirectory,
    .UserDomainMask, true)
let cachesPath: AnyObject = paths2[0]

var user:NSDictionary = [
    "Name": "Tom",
    "Address": "Tokyo",
]

let filePath = cachesPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("CachedUser")
let success = user.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

if success {
    println("save sucess")
}
```